# Filter values only present in one cohort

Tags: r, filtering

For my dataframe (testdat) of this structure I'd like to check for antigenes (AG) that are only present in the cohort B (In total there's 4 Cohorts: A, B, C, D). Vice versa these antigenes should have only NA values in Cohorts A, C and D.

```
## Patient Sample.Name Cohort Sex Age AG1    AG2    AG3 ...
## 1       HJWL_K      B       M  55  14.567 10.981 16.678 ...
## 2       JHD_P       A       M  67  12.447 11.948 NA     ...
## 3       NJIK_L      D       W  42  15.676 NA     NA     ...
## 4       DFR_O       C       M  56  14.675 13.342 13.832 ...
## 5       ...         ...    ... ...  ...     ...     ...
```

In total 'testdat' includes 260 rows (Patients) and 1150 columns (columns 1-5 Info like shown  above, 6:ncol(testdat) = AGs). Can I do that for the whole dataframe without a loop (testing AG by AG)?

I tried different approaches (e.g. group by(), filter(), select()) which either resulted in an error or gave me the result of 0 AGs (which I know can't be true). I think the underlying problem is, that can't get around to check for the actual AGs instead of just the cohorts.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want ("check for" is ambiguous)? Do you want to filter out rows based on another column, but only when cohort is B?

Comment: @richarddmorey: I'd like to select antigenes (columns) that have only been measured in Cohort B (vv only have NA values for the other cohorts). I also tried creating a new dataframe with the cohort names as columnnames and their respective mean value for each protein (rows), but got stuck there because the means I got were NA values, as soon as there's any NA value for the specific protein in the respective cohort.

Comment: @Basti: I tried                                                                                                          
 `testdat %>% 
  group_by(Cohort)%>% 
  filter(testdat,is.na(Cohort == "B") == FALSE & is.na(Cohort == "A") == TRUE 
         & is.na(Cohort == "C") == TRUE & is.na(Cohort == "D") == TRUE )`              But I think this is not specifiying that I'm looking for the values of the antigenes.

Comment: @alicia So you'd like list of columns that were not NA when cohort is B? eg, in your example, all antigens were represented in some other cohort (AG1 in all, AG2 in A and C, and AG3 in C), so the list would be empty? It would help to give an example if your desired output in an example set.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on cases assuming there are only 4 cohorts :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble) 
testdat=data.frame(Cohort=c("A","B","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","D"),
                                      AG1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                                      AG2=c(NA,1,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                   AG3=c(NA,1,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,NA),
                   AG4=c(1,1,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                   AG5=c(NA,NA,20,30,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

testdat %>%
  group_by(Cohort) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(all(is.na(.)))) %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "Cohort")%>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  filter(A==TRUE & B==FALSE & C==TRUE & D==TRUE) %>% rownames()
```

The idea is to tell if there is any AG for which A,C,D is NA in all cases while at least one sample from B show a value.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for! I got the following warning message:                         
`Warning message: funs() was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.`
 But after adjusting accordingly it worked just fine:                                                      
 `testdat %>%
+   group_by(Cohort) %>%
+   summarise_all(list(~all(is.na(.)))) %>%
+   column_to_rownames(var = "Cohort") %>%
+   t() %>%
+   as.data.frame() %>%
+   filter(A == TRUE & B == FALSE & C == TRUE & D == TRUE) %>%`